# How to use jQuery oninput function to display values of multiple input fields to a single input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use Jquery `on.(input, [...])` function to display what a user types in another input field.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.inputtext").on('input', function() {
    var inputtext = $(".inputtext").val();
    $(".showinput").val(inputtext);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" class="inputtext">
  <div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <input type="text" class="inputtext">
      <div>
        <div class="inputs">
          <input type="text" class="inputtext">
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="showinput">
```

However, the code only shows the entered text for the first input field.

I think I have to use a `for loop` but I dont't know how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work (value from actual field using 'this'):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input.inputtext").on('input', function (){
  var inputtext= $(this).val();    
  $(".showinput").val(inputtext);
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want only the inputed value to be in the showinput field.

Comment: @Efoskhi I see what you mean now:) you want to see the input from an actual field. see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks y'all. I was missing a "this" in the var inputtext syntax.

The correct script is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.inputtext").on('input', function (){
    var inputtext=$(this, ".inputtext").val();
    $(".showinput").val(inputtext);
  });
});
```